# Recursion SQL to TreeView C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AssetRegisterTreeGet]
    (@AssetID INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH results AS
    (
        SELECT
            AssetID, ParentAssetID, AssetNumber 
        FROM
            T_AssetRegister 
        WHERE 
            AssetID = @AssetID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            t.AssetID, t.ParentAssetID, t.AssetNumber 
        FROM
            T_AssetRegister t
        INNER JOIN
            results r ON r.ParentAssetID = t.AssetID
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM results 
    ORDER BY AssetID
    OPTION (maxrecursion 0);
END
```

The result looks like this:

```
AssetID   ParentAssetID     AssetNumber
----------------------------------------------
1         NULL              root
2         1                 Group
3         2                 Group - A
```

How can I use the stored procedure above to load it into an `<asp:TreeView>` in ASP.NET using C#?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this:

```
DataTable dtTree = new DataTable();
public void CollTree()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection((ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sconn"].ConnectionString)))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "AssetRegisterTreeGet";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@AssetID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dtTree);
            da.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        AddNodes(-2147483648, TreeView1.Nodes);
    }

    void AddNodes(int id, TreeNodeCollection tn)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtTree.Select("ParentAssetID = " + id))
        {
            TreeNode sub = new TreeNode(dr["AssetNumber"].ToString(), dr["AssetID"].ToString());
            tn.Add(sub);
            AddNodes(Convert.ToInt32(sub.Value), sub.ChildNodes);
        }
    }
```

Where `-2147483648` is the root id.
Thank you.